# Facebook iframe app scroolbars in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, iframe

This has surely been covered countless times, but I cannot find a working solution.

how do you get rid of the scrollbars in a Facebook iframe app in Chrome. Both IE & Firefox are fine.

Using the suggested CSS overflow:hidden, simply cuts off the content if its over 800px in height.

Even the Facebook Coca Cola iframe app has the content cut off!! see here
http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_161193133389

this is what is also happening to my app in Chrome (v. 16.0.912.77 m)

Comment: Which iframe what you are speaking about? TAB or Canvas?

Comment: tab ifram app, have a look at the coca-cola page & click on the 'Home' 'tab/link' you will see in Chrome the content gets cut off (past the 800px height)

Comment: Chrome v16 is old... i'm using v19 and I have no scrollbars

Comment: No problems which are related to scrollbars here (Chrome 20-beta). You might want to check it in https though (unsecure content on page). Fyi Chrome 16 is old and normal human beings are at least at 18 or 19. Restarting your browser may help :p

Answer (score 2):

add this to your canvas app's fb js:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: X });
```

where X is the height you want.

If your app is fluid use:

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention my app page has a dynamic height, the above code, is what I already use & it works fine in FF & IE, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Have yet set the <!DOCTYPE   ? I'm 99% sure you aren't ;)

Comment: yes I am...<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I would also try to set the size with a delay and experiment with it a little:

```
window.setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1111 })", 2000);
```

Also don't forget to initialize Facebook with your app id ( `FB.init` ) **before** calling `FB.Canvas.setSize` or `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow`.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue:  after adding FB JS SDK and

> FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

i had to set

> body{}

in css to keep the scroll bars from showing in chrome.  In my case is was padding.

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a few tweaks to you app. First, add the following code to your page:

`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();` to tell the Facebook SDK to resize the iframe if the contents is longer.

Add `overflow: hidden` to the `<html>` or `<body>` CSS

Check your app settings and make sure you have set the Canvas Width to 'fluid' and Canvas Height to 'fixed' (Go to Settings > Advanced > Scroll to Canvas Settings.)

All of these things should fix the scroll bars. If it doesn't, using something like "Inspect Element" in Chrome  to see if something is causing the bars to appear.

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions you could try below. Please comment as to which one, or if none of them work and I will update this answer accordingly.

1. If you haven't already, try adding: `body{overflow:hidden;}`
2. You may also have javascript disabled.
3. Alternatively, you could set the fixed height for the app very high in the app settings, where it says: **fixed[ ]**. Also make sure that fixed is selected on your app settings.
4. If this happens on other apps, including that CocaCola page you mentioned, then it could possibly be the browser. Try updating. I use the Chrome 19.0.1084.56 and I have no problems, (except for me the height is always pushed to a **1200px** maximum height).
5. Also look here: '[Choosing between Facebook iframe scrollbar or page cut off halfway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745969/choosing-between-facebook-iframe-scrollbar-or-page-cut-off-halfway)' where there is a solution that you can try.
6. **Edit:** Also look here: '[Timeline page app height stuck at 800px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626136/timeline-page-app-height-stuck-at-800px)'.

***Edit:*** After some looking through the Facebook bug area, Facebook say this is not a bug on Facebook's end, therefore must be a problem in your code. (Source: 'https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/360687100649759')

If that doesn't work, then comment and say so and I will do some further research.