# ASP.NET MVC Facebook SDK setAutoGrow

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK from [here](http://facebooksdk.net/)

I have a relatively simple iFrame app which is in a frame which Facebook defaults to 800px high. I want to make this iFrame higher to get rid of the scrollbars.

Looking at questions like [Timeline page app height stuck at 800px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626136/timeline-page-app-height-stuck-at-800px) it appears I need to use the `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();` command.

I can't see how to do this within the ASP.NET C# Facebook SDK, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) is part of the JavaScript SDK.  You will need to call this method via JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Yes, I know I need to call that. The question is really how do I do that within the context of the .NET Facebook SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately the .net sdk can't really help you out here.  That sdk is mostly just a wrapper for Facebook's REST methods.  The functionality you are looking for is only in their JS sdk.  If you were using webforms instead of MVC, you could do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828602/1000175 but that would still require the use of the js sdk.  I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @Fisch is correct. Every Facebook app I have developed with the Facebook C# SDK also implemented the Facebook JavaScript SDK. Normally, I would do this in a Master Page.