# Choosing between Facebook iframe scrollbar or page cut off halfway

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I have an iframe tab in facebook. I used "overflow:hidden" in the body tag and this code at the bottom of my page:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">  
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId : 'MY_APP_ID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true // parse XFBML
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);
       };
       (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + 
         '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);   
       }());
      </script>
```

This removes the scrollbars and resizes the iframe. The problem is that my page is cut off after about 800px (that leaves about 400px). I've set the height in facebook to "fluid". It works absolutely fine in every other browser but not in IE8.

As a side question, why does IE still exist? It's the absolute worst thing. Anyways, I added this to the head:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
body{overflow-y:scroll;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But that just gets me back to having the scrollbars again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB.Canvas.setAutoResize has been renamed to [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/)

Also, to use this method, the height of your app needs to be set to static, not fluid.

You can also try [FB.Canvas.stSize()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/).

I have found that sometimes these methods can be a little buggy, but if you keep calling them, the Facebook parent window eventually gets the message.  This being the case, you may want to try something like this:

```
setInterval(FB.Canvas.setSize, 500);
```

Comment: to be specific, it doesn't change anything. In IE the content still cuts off.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a different approach.  Can you try that to see if it works for you?